# A Custom UINavigationBar Image Shrinks the UIPageViewController when visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uipageviewcontroller

I am building a simple app that contains a `UITableViewController` and when the user clicks on a cell, it loads up a few images in a `UIPageViewController`.

In order to utilise the space of the device, I am hiding the `UINavigationBar` in the `UIPageViewController`, but getting it back with one click with the following code in the `viewDidLoad` of the `UIPageViewController`.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnTap = true;

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

With this, the `UINavigationBar` just comes down and does not distort the size of the image, as can be seen below.

[image]

[image]

You can see the placement of the image and that it does not get distorted. When the bar comes down, it just comes over the image.

However, if I place a `UINavigationBar` image on the `UITableViewCell` of the `UITableViewController` that called this `UIPageViewController`, it distorts the image by shrinking it:

[image]

[image]

Why does this occur with a custom image?

I am not applying the image in the `AppDelegate` or the `UIPageViewController`; I am specifically applying the image on each `UITableViewController` in the following form:

```
- (void)appTheme
{
    BasicsThemeManager *themeManager = [BasicsThemeManager sharedManager];
    themeManager.backgrounds = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Basicslogoblue.png"]];
    self.leafletCollectionView.backgroundView = themeManager.backgrounds;
    UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Basicslogobluenav.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Basicslogobluetab.png"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];

}
```

When the cell is clicked, I call the `didSelectMethod` in the following way:

```
if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Chinese - 汉语"])
{
    NSArray *leafletImages = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    leafletImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[[ImageModel alloc] initWithImageName:@"ThreeFactsChinesePage1.png"], [[ImageModel alloc] initWithImageName:@"ThreeFactsChinesePage2.png"], [[ImageModel alloc] initWithImageName:@"ThreeFactsChinesePage3.png"], [[ImageModel alloc] initWithImageName:@"ThreeFactsChinesePage4.png"], [[ImageModel alloc] initWithImageName:@"ThreeFactsChinesePage5"], [[ImageModel alloc] initWithImageName:@"ThreeFactsChinesePage6"], nil];


    LeafletImageViewController *tutorial = [[LeafletImageViewController alloc] initWithImages:leafletImages];
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tutorial];
    [self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:^{
        tutorial.title = @"3 Facts";
    }];
}
```

**Issues**

When I have a `UIPageViewController`, I don't actually need to have an image on the `UINavigationBar`; I don't mind it just being black, but how do I do that? Even if I set the following code in the `viewDidLoad` of the `UIPageViewController`, it still shows the image:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

I'm guessing it's taking the image and passing it across because it is embedded in a `Navigation Controller`, but I don't know how to get passed this issue because I don't want the image of the `UIPageViewController` to shrink. Alternatively, I don't mind keeping the app as it is now if I can get the `UIPageViewController` to not shrink when the `UINavigationBar` is shown.

Any guidance would be appreciated.